# the_post(); prints out style text into my HTML?

Tags: php, wp-query, loop

Every time I use `the_post();` in my theme code, the following is echo'ed into my pages:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .formTitle {
        font-size:20px;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    }
    .formDescription {
        font-size:16px;
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    .formElement {
        margin-bottom:15px;
    }
    .formElement .textbox {
        font-size: 16px;
        width:97%;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding:2px;
    }
    .formElement .title {
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .checkbox, .radio {
        font-weight:normal;
    }
    .button {
        margin-top:10px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .required {
        color:red;
    }
    -->
    </style>
```

Where in the world is this from? What is it? How do I stop it from being printed out?

Comment: Do you have any form plugins that may be causing that? Can you share a sample of how you're using it in the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the actions and filters being used in your plugins and themes. I'm assuming something is hooked into `the_post` action somewhere. Dumping the following globals give you a peek behind the curtain here.

```
global $wp_actions, $wp_filters;
```

Once you identify the source, you either queue up the CSS properly in the HEAD, or remove it altogether.

```
remove_action('the_post', 'function_name');
```

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot. I was able to identify a poorly-written plugin that was spitting out that stuff when `the_post()` was called. Plugin should have been hooking `the_header()` or `the_footer()` instead.